# GuzzleHttp\Client change base url dynamically

Tags: php, rest, http, guzzle

I am working on a project with a restful API. I use GuzzleHttp library in order to get/put etc. data in the API.

Is there any way where you can change GuzzleHttp\Client's base url on the run. My idea is because I have multiple endpoints of one api but the base url is not the same so I want to create one Client with some options but change the base url when I want to execute some request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it is written in GuzzleHttp's documentation, if you pass absolute path to post/get/put, etc. it will override the current base url. So, if you prepend the absolute path it will get the job done. [Check here, GuzzleHttp documentation](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/client.html#base-urls)

Comment: This works, but I wish there was a `setConfig` or perhaps even a `setBaseUri` method on `Client`. The full URI method just doesn't seem like a clean approach.

Comment: As mentioned in [an issue](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1419), since Guzzle 6, clients are immutable, therefore altering their state makes no sense. You can still use a custom factory to create a client with appropriate base url.

Answer (score 6):

Up to version 5 of Guzzle, you can use `setDefaultOption` method:

```
$client->setDefaultOption('base_uri', 'https://example.url');
```

Comment: There is no such method. Please elaborate.

Comment: I believe by saying `up to version 5`, OP implies that after version 5, such method is deprecated (gone)